# Parsing HTML with embedded code (PHP, Ruby, etc)

Tags: php, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

OK, so you all know PHP can parse `.php` documents, containing HTML code, with embedded PHP code. And I believe Ruby (Erb) allows pretty much the same thing.

But, how does it do it? (Trust me I've had good look into the sources, but spotting something like this in 1mil. lines of code is not the easiest thing).

**What I thought is :**

- What matters is what is being `echo`ed
- The initial PHP/HTML text is converted to a valid PHP script
- PHP code, as indicated by `<?php` and `?>` starting/ending points, remains as-is
- The rest is converted using `echo` statements.

**E.g. :**

```
<html>
     <head>
           <title><?php echo "This is the title"; ?></title>
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
</html>
```

**Converted to :**

```
echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<title>";
echo "This is the title";
echo "</title>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

Would that make sense?

---

**P.S.** If you're wondering about the very nature of the question, I'm currently building something like for a language of my own. And it works rather fine, though I'm experiencing some conversion speed issues for longer input documents, so I though of exploring my alternatives... :-)

Comment: _Would that make sense?_ No. Raw HTML (outside the `<?php ?>` tags) is written straight to the output buffer.

Comment: @MikeW Sounds rather sensible. However how would a block (e.g. a `foreach`) broken in parts be handled? Example : `<?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?><h3><?php echo $post->title; ?></h3><?php } ?>`

Comment: The PHP interpreter recognises the block structure and handles enclosed HTML tags as part of the processing, but ths really is far too broad a question for [so]

Comment: I've not tried it, but I wonder if the `Reflection` system will show you how this is parsed in PHP? I suspect it will have a token for "HTML block", and otherwise everything else is parsed as a normal scripting language would be. There are whole books dedicated to parser design, that might be worth looking into also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may get down voted because I don't have any references, but...

> What you're referring to is how every referential IT system works. It
>   takes data from a dynamic resource (either external or on-page) &
>   appends it into the page

I want to call it [`parsing`](http://www.techterms.com/definition/parse) but I don't think that's the right technical term. My thinking is in PHP, your page will first go through PHP (where it will output any PHP elements as plain text), and then that parsed document will be sent to the front-end HTML processor

So to answer your question, I would say that you're probably over-complicating it. HTML is the base-standard for output, so why re-invent the wheel? Your parser should only look for its relevant tags & then run the code inside. It doesn't have to recognize the HTML inside - just treat it all as plain text, unless you want to render more of your code

> If what you proposed was right, we wouldn't have to write *any* HTML
>   in Rails or PHP. We'd just use the in-built methods

For example:

```
<p><? echo "hello" ?></p>
```

In my simplistic definition, PHP would first render the "plain text" output for the `<? ?>`, and then send the formatted page to the front-end as HTML